# Thread-local storage in struct

Tags: c, gcc

I want to use c for an upcoming project and while trying out some concepts that I will need, I came across the following problem. Lets say I have a struct like this:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    int fixedValue;
    int changingValue;  
};
```

In main, I will malloc an instance of this struct into a global pointer and fill the fixedValue member. Then there will be multiple threads reading that fixedValue and changing the changingValue. Thus, changingValue should be exclusive for every thread, i.e. ever thread has its own. Ideally, I am looking for something like __thread that would allow me to do that. Of course, I could change changingValue into an array but that would make the code much messier. Thus, I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Which is it? They'll all be modifying the struct, or each thread should have its own struct? Your specs are self-contradictory.

Comment: I can't conceive of way to put direct thread-local storage as a member a struct.  Alternatives are putting the whole thing in TLS, or - probably better - use `int *changingValue` as a *pointer* to individual thread-local values.

Comment: @ikegami: There will be one struct, each thread should share one fixedValue but have its own changingValue

Comment: You just repeated yourself. One struct, or one per thread? You can't have have it both ways

Comment: They explained themself just fine: they want a central single struct, all threads sharing the `fixedValue` but each thread getting their own `changingValue`.

Comment: @ikegami: Well, but that is exactly what I want. I malloc a global variable in main and then create multiple threads, all accessing that one variable. I just want to have that one member thread-local while sharing the other one. As I said, I could use an array and just share the whole thing, but that just makes it much messier.

Comment: @Steve Friedl, No, they did not. You can't say you want to malloc `sizeof(int)*2` and say you want to malloc enough for each thread. Those are mutually exclusive

Comment: They explained themselves just fine; the problem is that what they want isn't possible.

Comment: @Steve Friedl, Which is what I've been saying. You're the one who introduced the idea they they didn't explain themselves, not I (I was just using your words for what I was saying when I said "No, they did not.")

Comment: @ikegami fair enough.  Impossible problems generate interesting solutions :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is impossible because your requirements are self-contradictory. You can't use `malloc` to allocate a block of memory large enough to store two `int`, yet also allocate enough memory to store an arbitrary number of `int` objects using that same `malloc`.

Comment: Well, what I’ve been looking for is basically syntactic sugar. Of course, you would need to malloc sufficient space, I was just looking for a way that the complier would do this for me. I could change changingValue to a pointer, malloc how ever much space I need and make sure that the threads just access their respective index.

Comment: Re "*you would need to malloc sufficient space*", There's no point in allocating more memory than the structure will use.

Comment: Re "*what I’ve been looking for is basically syntactic sugar*", No, you specifically requested the use of a structure that's too small to contain the necessary info.

Comment: Yes, but the struct would require more space, that is the point. Obviously, I was looking for something that would do this for me. Weather this could be done using a modifier like __thread, or using some datastruct ThreadStruct, or simply is not implemented in c the language was my question.

Comment: Re "*Yes, but the struct would require more space*", There's no point in allocating more memory than the structure will use.

Comment: But it will use it

Comment: No, not without adding members, which you clearly don't want to do. You specifically said you wanted to use `changingValue`

Comment: Anyway, I guess we can agree that it just simply not there. No further discussion needed.

Answer (score 1):

All the subobjects of an object *O* have the same storage class as *O* (if any).  It follows that if objects *O<sub>1</sub>* and *O<sub>2</sub>* are both subobjects of the same object, then they have the same storage class as each other.  This is reflected by the fact that C does not permit structure or union member declarations to bear storage-class specifiers (`static`, `extern`, `auto`, `_Thread_local`, *etc*).  Instead, C17 says:

> If an aggregate or union object is declared with a storage-class specifier other than
> `typedef`, the properties resulting from the storage-class specifier,
> except with respect to linkage, also apply to the members of the
> object, and so on recursively for any aggregate or union member
> objects.

(C2017, 6.7.1/8)

You say,

> In main, I will malloc an instance of this struct into a global pointer

, but this will not achieve your objective of providing both one object shared among threads and multiple distinct per-thread objects. Moreover, it's not clear why you intend to allocate an object at all, as opposed to simply declaring one directly.

If threads must share `fixedValue` and have their own `changingValue`s, then these cannot usefully be members of the same structure.  You need to separate them.  Moreover, although C does have built-in support for thread-local storage since C11, it is usually easier and better to use other mechanisms to provide for per-thread data, such as local variables of the thread function.

Comment: I need to allocate it dynamically as I will need more than one such struct based on user input. I just simplified the example. Imagine something like a simulation tool or solver. Every struct represents some object, with fixedValue being some sort of identifier and changingValue maybe some sort of cost that the simulation assigns to this object. Every thread will work on the same, user provided instance.

Comment: The main thread parses this instance, sets the (external) id to the fixed value and then creates multiple worker threads that try to find a solution to a problem, thereby assign the cost to changingValue for their solution. Different threads might find different solutions and thus assign a different cost to this object.

Comment: @Gorid, if you want a separate `changingValue` for each thread then you need somehow to allocate a separate one for each thread.  If you want the main thread to be able to access all of them later, as it sounds like you do, then neither thread-local storage nor variables local to the thread function will do -- the main thread needs to *explicitly* provide storage for each child to use.